# How to split text as android textview

Tags: android, textview

how to split text as android textview by split() or matcher. When I split the text I want to keep also delimeters.  I have used

```
 Pattern stuff = Pattern.compile("[\\s]|[\\w+]");
```

and

```
 split("(?<!^|[a-zA-Z'])|(?![a-zA-Z'])")
```

but result is not what I expected. it's not splitting like textview in android

Example would be any text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply! dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Comment: post an example of the text that you try to split.

Comment: @Elenasys question is edited

Comment: ok in your text what would be the delimiters? the space, "." ?

Comment: @Elenasys I don't know how textview divides text into words/sentences that's way I don't which delimeters would be. For know I think it would be space(must support multiple spaces), "-",".","," . And I also want to keep delimeters

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the text to be split as sentences, like below

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

I used the String's split function like below.

```
String[] results = source.split("!|\\.|\\?");
```

hope it helps.

additional, if you want to keep the delimiters, below is the sample.

```
    String[] results = source.split("!|\\.|\\?");

    int offset = 0;
    for(String result : results){

        offset += result.length();
        // just append the delimiter after the split sub string.
        Log.d("", "result = " + result + source.charAt(offset));
        offset +=1;
    }
```

Comment: And I also want to keep delimeters