# Send sms from text view with click button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to know how can I send a sms getting the textview information with one button , I dont need receive message , only send the textview information clicking the button for a specific number

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read about Intents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you done so far? I would suggest using an implicit intent that triggers an sms client in your phone when the button is clicked, like this:

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("tel:123456");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "sms text");
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

`"sms text"` should be your textView text. You can do something like this instead

```
yourTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Button sendtext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendtext);
        sendtext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("tek:999");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,smsUri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", textViewew1.getText().toString());
                intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}

Comment: I did this but does not work i receive error when i click de button

Comment: Ok I resolve the problem thanks so much

Comment: no worries, you can accept the answer as correct

Comment: For sure but before I would like to know how i can separate the different text view ,because when i see in the message on the phone all.is together i have to use /n or something like that?

Comment: Do you mean splitting as sentences? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337292/6683139

Comment: Its ok I rosolve the space problem between variable with some +""+ , I would like to know if is possible send the message to the default phone number, because when i put some nunber kn this lane Uri sms Uri = Uri.parse ("tel:1234"); I have to put the number when the intent start .